# Rendering a scene2d ui on top of box2d

Tags: user-interface, camera, libgdx, box2d, scene2d

Im currently having issues with rendering a UI on top of a box2d playarea. As of currently the button is rendered in the corner of the screen but does not react on clicks as it seems the screen believes it isnt there. Only the picture of it. Below is the code of how a screen works. What order things are being rendered. The cam zoom,update and set before and after the spritebatch begin and end was a test that resulted in the sprite in the corner, but it still does not do anything. I'm very stumped and would appreciate some advice in how to handle the rendering in a good way.

```
public synchronized void render(float delta) {
    getCamControll().update();

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // RENDER SPRITES
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    batch.begin();

    Iterator<Renderable> itr = renderables.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Renderable r = itr.next();
        r.render(batch);
    }

    batch.end();

    // RENDER DEBUG
    sr.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    sr.begin(ShapeType.Line);
    for (Renderable r : renderables) {
        r.debug(sr);
    }
    sr.end();

    // RENDER GUI
    float camzoom = cam.zoom;
    Vector3 camPos = cam.position.cpy();
    cam.zoom = 1;
    cam.position.set(Vector2.Zero, cam.position.z);
    cam.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(new Matrix4());
    if (stage != null) {
        batch.begin();
        stage.draw();
        Array<Actor> actors = stage.getActors();
        batch.end();
    }

    cam.zoom = camzoom;
    cam.position.set(camPos);
    cam.update();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set up your input handler correctly, i.e. somewhere in your setup/init code (after you've created your stage) you need:

```
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```

If box2d (or anything else) also needs to handle input in addition to the scene, you should look at Libgdx's InputMultiplexer for combining input handlers.

Comment: Box2D doesn't know anything about input handling, or even rendering at all. It's a pure physics engine which even runs in C++ and not even Java :)

Comment: Ok, thanks, haven't used Box2D myself yet. Then the code I posted should be sufficient.

Comment: @noone but if he needs the inputprocessor to move his `Sprite`s (and i think that is the case) he needs to set an `InputMultiplexer`.

Comment: @Springrbua If he wants two different handlers for input, then he will need a multiplexer, yes. But Box2D doesn't need one for sure.

Comment: I am confused. How will an inputmultiplexer help here? I want the UI to follow the screen but the box2d to not do so. Thus rendering UI with buttons on top.

Comment: You said your rendering allready works right? So you just need to set your `Stage` as the `InputProcessor` (see the answer). Only if you have to handle inputs somewhere else you need to use InputMultiplexer, as your Game can only have 1 InputProcessor.

Comment: Lucas, one step at the time! First get your UI to react to your button. Then you can move on to moving stuff around. Your question was about reacting to the button.

Comment: But it does react to the button. It only stopped reacting once I messed with the camera. The cam.zoom, cam.position.set(campos) and cam.update parts before and after the batch begin and batch end. If I remove those. The button reacts just fine. But it is very small on the box2d screen, and doesnt follow the camera when i move around.

Comment: Sorry, english is not my main language. So I might have come out as a bit vague.

Comment: If "reacting to camera" actually means stage being disposed (e.g. recreated), then that may have something to do with it. You should typically set up your scene outside the render parts of your code, and only when needed.

Comment: By react I mean that you can click on it. I want it to move with the camera and still be able to be clicked on. Because as of currently you can move around in the box2d world but the button itself is only rendered on a fixed position of the screen.

Comment: Make sure you are not recreating the stage. We're way off your original question already, and you should ask another one and share more relevant code (how and where your stage gets created) if your problem changed to "button stops reacting when I move camera around".

Comment: True enough. Ill post a different question as this part is solved.